# How do you use iTunes Affiliates Search API to find a song title from a specific artist

Tags: ios, url, itunes, affiliates

I am trying to use the [iTunes Affiliate Search API](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html) in my iPhone App to search for content within the iTunes Store. An example URL to search for "I Want To Hold Your Hand" is:

```
http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=i+want+to+hold+your+hand&entity=song
```

This search finds all songs with the title "I Want To Hold Your Hand". However, I only want to find the songs that are by The Beatles. I tried the following to narrow the search, but it did not work:

```
http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=i+want+to+hold+your+hand&entity=song&term=beatles&entity=musicartist
```

This just provides the same result.

How do you construct a URL to find a song title from specific artist using itunes.apple.com/search

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Will you be happy with the results if you include "the beatles" into your search term?

```
http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=the+beatles+i+want+to+hold+your+hand&entity=song
```

If not, it seems you'll have to do some post processing to the results of the query.

Comment: thanks, but that would still require post processing with the search string you suggested. You may be right that post processing is the only way.

Comment: Well if you follow the method suggested by Irene you would land up with search results having "The Beatles" in it and thus expanding the result contrary to narrowing it